# Serving the inception model v3 in Java using SavedModelBundle

Tags: java, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Using org.tensorflow:tensorflow:1.3.0-rc0.

I have generated the inception model from the checkpoints as per the tutorial https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception:

```
inception_saved_model --checkpoint_dir=/root/xmod/inception-v3
```

This went OK and generated a saved_model.pb and a variables/ subdirectory with data and I moved all this content to the /tmp/inception-model directory.
Now I'm trying to use this model by essentially converting https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java 
I am loading the model like this with no errors:

```
SavedModelBundle modelBundle = SavedModelBundle.load("/tmp/inception-model", "serve");
```

Now I am trying to formulate the query (similar to this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java#L112) but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to use the feed and fetch methods:

```
    private static float[] executeInceptionGraph(SavedModelBundle modelBundle, Tensor image) throws Exception {
     Tensor result = modelBundle.session().runner().feed(???).fetch(???).run().get(0);
```

Any help how to write this query is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the [javadoc on session runners](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Session.Runner)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed your input (here your tensor image) associated to the name of its node in the graph, from the link you posted it seems that the tutorial uses "images" (see here https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py#L49, code with the python query to the server built in the tutorial https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception).
Then you fetch your output node with its name too, looking at a sample of the server response here https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception you can get "classes" or "scores" depending which one you'd like to have.

So one of the two command should work:

```
Tensor result = modelBundle.session().runner().feed("images", image).fetch("classes").run().get(0);
```

OR

```
 Tensor result = modelBundle.session().runner().feed("images", image).fetch("scores").run().get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it works with frozen models only. The argument to the fetch method is the one used in freeze_graph argument output_node_names. See https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/export_inference_graph.py#L32